# App crashes on service start

Tags: java, android, eclipse, service

im trying to start a service from an activity, but when the button click calls it the simulator stops my application and tells me: "the application (...) has stopped unexpectedly. please try again"

**In my manifest i have**:

`<service android:name=".MainService" android:enabled="true" android:label="Main      Service"></service>`

**The code i use to call the service (from TimerGuardActivity)**:

`Intent i = new Intent(TimerGuardActivity.this, MainService.class);
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            TimerGuardActivity.this.startService(i);`

**The whole service itself**:

```
package com.AirplaneModeGuard;

import java.util.Calendar;

import android.app.Service;

import android.content.Intent;

import android.content.SharedPreferences;

import android.os.IBinder;

import android.preference.PreferenceManager;

import android.provider.Settings;

public class MainService extends Service {

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;    

}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onStart(intent, startId);

    SharedPreferences preferences =     PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());     
    boolean guardE = preferences.getBoolean("guardenabled", false);
    boolean nightE = preferences.getBoolean("nightsleepenabled", false);

    if(guardE&&!nightE)
    {
        guard(false,-1);            
    }
    if(guardE&&nightE)
    {
        guard(true,checkTimeForGuard());
    }
    if(nightE&&!guardE)
    {
        nightSleep(false);
    }
    if(!guardE&&!nightE)
    {
        Intent i=new Intent(this,MainService.class);
        stopService(i);   
    }



}

private void guard(final boolean nightsleeptoggled, final int timeToRun)
{
    if(nightsleeptoggled&&timeToRun==-1){
        nightSleep(true);
        return;
    }
    new Thread(new Runnable(){
           int minutesCount=0;
           SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
           int minNum = preferences.getInt("checkeveryM", 10) ;//shared preferences

            public void run() {

                if(nightsleeptoggled)
                {
            while(true)
            {
               try {
                Thread.sleep(60000); // one minute (1000= 1sec)
                minutesCount++;

                if(minutesCount>= timeToRun)
                    break;
                if(minutesCount % minNum==0)
                {

                ToggleAirplaneMode(false);
                    Thread.sleep(60000);
                ToggleAirplaneMode(true);

                }  
                   } 
               catch (InterruptedException e) 
               {
                e.printStackTrace();
               } 
            }
            nightSleep(true);
                }

                else
                {
                    minNum*=6000;
                    while(true)
                    {
                       try 
                       {
                        Thread.sleep(minNum); // one minute
                        ToggleAirplaneMode(false);
                            Thread.sleep(60000);
                        ToggleAirplaneMode(true);                          
                       } 
                       catch (InterruptedException e) 
                        {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        } 
                  }                     
                }

            }
            }).start();
    return;

}

private void nightSleep(boolean guardE)
{

    int TimeToSleep = checkTimeToSleep();
    if(TimeToSleep<0)
    {
        guard(true,checkTimeForGuard());
        return;
    }
    try{
        ToggleAirplaneMode(false);
        Thread.sleep(TimeToSleep*1000);
        ToggleAirplaneMode(true);

        if(guardE)
        {
            guard(true, checkTimeForGuard());
        }
        return;
    }
    catch (InterruptedException e) 
    {
    e.printStackTrace();
    } 

}

private int checkTimeToSleep()//take values of sleeptime and wakeuptime from shared preferences and calculate the total amount of minutes to sleep 
    //if the current hour is after the sleeptime use it as the sleeptime.
{
    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    int sleepM = preferences.getInt("SleepM", 0);
    int sleepH = preferences.getInt("SleepH", 0);
    int wakeupM = preferences.getInt("WakeUpM", 0);
    int wakeupH = preferences.getInt("WakeUpH", 0);
    int finalTime=0;
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(); 
    int minutes = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    int hours = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);

    if(sleepH==wakeupH)
    {
        if(sleepM>wakeupM)
            finalTime =wakeupM-sleepM;
        else
            finalTime=1440-(wakeupM-sleepM);
    }

    if(sleepH>wakeupH)
    {
        if(hours<wakeupH || hours>sleepH)
        {
            if(hours<24 && hours>sleepH){
                sleepH=hours;
                sleepM=minutes;
            }
            else{
                sleepH= hours+24;
                sleepM=minutes;
                }
        }
        if(hours==sleepH && minutes>sleepM)
            sleepM=minutes;
        if(hours==wakeupH && minutes<wakeupM)
        {
            wakeupM=minutes;
            sleepH=hours+24;
        }
        finalTime = 60*(24-sleepH+wakeupH);
        finalTime+=(wakeupM-sleepM);
    }

    else if(sleepH<wakeupH)
    {
        if(hours>=wakeupH && hours<=sleepH)
        {
            sleepH=hours;
            sleepM=minutes;
        }
        finalTime = 60*(sleepH-wakeupH);
        finalTime+=(wakeupM-sleepM);
    }

    return finalTime;
}

private int checkTimeForGuard() //checks the amount of minutes guard should run in case nightsleep is enabled
{
    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(); 
    int minutes = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    int hours = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    int sleepM = preferences.getInt("SleepM", 0);
    int sleepH = preferences.getInt("SleepH", 0);
    int wakeupM = preferences.getInt("WakeUpM", 0);
    int wakeupH = preferences.getInt("WakeUpH", 0);

    int value=0;



    if(sleepH>wakeupH)
    {
        if(hours<wakeupH || hours>sleepH)  
            return -1;
        if(hours==sleepH && minutes>sleepM)
            return -1;
        if(hours==wakeupH && minutes<wakeupM)
            return -1;
        value = 1440-checkTimeToSleep();
        value-=((60*(hours-wakeupH))+(minutes-wakeupM));
    }

    else if(sleepH<wakeupH)
    {
        if(hours>wakeupH && hours<sleepH)
            return -1;
        if(hours==sleepH && minutes>sleepM)
            return -1;
        if(hours==wakeupH && minutes<wakeupM)
            return -1;

        if(hours>=sleepH)
        {
            value=60*(sleepH-hours);
            value+=(sleepM-minutes);
        }
        if(hours<=wakeupH)
        {
            value=60*(24+sleepH-hours);
            value+=(sleepM-minutes);
        }
    }

    return value;
}

private void ToggleAirplaneMode(boolean isEnabled)//turn off airplanemode (radiation on)=true, on=false
{
    Settings.System.putInt(
            getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(),
              Settings.System.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON, isEnabled ? 0 : 1);
}}
```

EDIT:

Please help me im stuck here for almost a month

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/89/error1poh.png/

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/405/errorlog.png/

Comment: what is at line 39 of TimerGuardActivity ? (or even better post the whole code). This is where the null pointer comes from apparently.

Comment: can you please show your TimerGuardActivity and error on your logcat it will help us where the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

your stopService(i) method crashing the app.